# django-mptt & django 1.2

Tags: django, django-mptt

From the homepage of django-mptt

> Version 0.2.1 is not compatible with Django 1.0 and above - please use SVN trunk for now

I tend to avoid using trunk for work that is going live any time soon, But I have a rush job.

Does it work with Django 1.2, (beyond "hello world" equivalents) Does anyone have any current experience / odd bugs to share etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJango-mptt on Google Code seems to have been abandoned, but there are a couple of forks on Github.

This one uses subclasses instead of registering the models, which makes in easier to use: http://github.com/bfirsh/django-mptt

However I'd recommend this fork, actively developed by one of the FeinCMS developers, which I've used with Django 1.2:

http://github.com/matthiask/django-mptt/

Comment: The updates page seems to indicate it is still active to some extent, last upload 11 days ago, but yeah, wiki pages from 2008!

Comment: following on, edit timeout.

the other ones seem even less active no commits since 2010-04-12 for matthiask, 2010-03-22 for brfish,

Also, i just found http://github.com/tabo/django-treebeard which looks like a viable alternative to django-mptt, 

Grr! .. I'm going to go with the original mptt from trunk for now, but I have a sneaking suspicion along the route I may be able to simplify the project to some extent, removing the need for any of the above!

Comment: Are we talking about the same package - django-mptt on Google Code? Last updated Jul 1 2009?

http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/source/list

matthiask version definitely has fewer bugs, and is compatible with the original svn trunk, so I'd still advise using that instead.

Comment: ah.. so it's been a while since i've looked at google code, i had mistakenly looked at the update dates on the issues, not the updates to the code, doh! thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: As far as I can tell this doesn't play well with 1.2.1 multidb support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the trunk version since Django 1.2 is out and haven't run into any problems with that! Can't promise you that it will work for you; for known issues have a look at their tracker: http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/issues/list